# Can i use authorize/authentication for custom database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorize-attribute

Can i use authorization for custom database like i have created my own user table which have following attributes and at the same time can i use the authorization to check that if user is logged in then it checks that what is the role of user so he/she can view the page or not.

UserName 
Role 
ID etc.

I have tried Session["UserName"] and many things to manage the login system but it didn't worked 
eg i have three views Managerpage Testerpage Developerpage each can view the related page according to roles Manager Tester and Developer.

Thank You in advance
please dnt block me just ask me if i cant explain my problem.

Comment: Where's your SQL query? Include it in your question please.

Comment: There isn't even a question here. Try this is a starting point. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Friends i cant post another question, so if u can you help me out in this problem so thank you. Should i create new controller for each table or single controller for all the tables, following are the tables 1- Users 2- Projects 3- User_Projects (For many to many relation) 4- Components (Components of projects) 5- Bugs @JonathonOgden Thank You

Comment: I am adding models in the asp.net web application in Visual studio so should i import all the tables in one model and use single controller to use them or should i make separate models and their controllers. @SeanLange Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going based on your picture.  You should really provide more information if you are going to ask a question in the future.

```
SELECT UID 
FROM dbo.User_Project
WHERE PID = '1';
```

Comment: Select [User].FName , [User].LName , [User].[Role]
From [User]
where [User].ID IN
(
 Select User_Project.[UID]
 from User_Project
 where User_Project.PID = 2
)
This one Worked

Comment: Friends i cant post another question, so if u can you help me out in this problem so thank you.

Should i create new controller for each table or single controller for all the tables, following are the tables

1- Users
2- Projects 
3- User_Projects     (For many to many relation)
4- Components       (Components of projects)
5- Bugs

Comment: what do you mean by controller?

Comment: I am adding models in the asp.net web application in Visual studio so should i import all the tables in one model and use single controller to use them or should i make separate models and their controllers.
Thank You!

Comment: I would like to elaborate my question that should i use my each table in sql as a model and create its controller to perform operations or should i use single model to import whole database and single controller to use it
Thank You!

Comment: I'm not well versed in MVC or asp.net.  I doubt anyone will answer your question buried in the comments of an answered question.  I'd look elsewhere for the answers. sorry